# i have installed crystal report 13.0 for my vs 2019 but i have got an error that crystal repot 10.5.3700 is missing

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Crystal Report 13.0 is installed all resources are included but I cannot run successfully my vb.net project where error is shown crystalreport 10.5.3700.0 is missing

error is
System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: The error message is clear, seems like you have a missing dll or a conflict of version.
I suggest you double check your references.

Comment: The error references version 10.5.3700.0. Is your Visual Studio project still referencing this older version after installing version 13.0?